# iptables rules not being applied on reboot despite netfilter-persistent being an enabled service

Tags: networking, systemd, iptables, firewall

My aim is to have a collection of `iptables` rules be loaded on startup. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1.

I have a collection of `iptables` rules defined in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`. I have `iptables-persistent` and `netfilter-persistent` installed. The latter is an enabled `systemd` service and it successfully runs after a reboot, as `systemctl status netfilter-persistent` indicates, but the rules defined in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` are *not* applied after a reboot.

Crucially: manually restarting the service (`systemctl restart netfilter-persistent`) causes the rules to be loaded. The service works and the rules are valid. It's as if some other service is coming along after `netfilter-persistent` runs and exits, wiping away the rules.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have no idea how to proceed, as nobody else seems to have this problem.

If any other details would be helpful, please let me know. I feel as though I'm losing my mind.

**Edit:** The contents of `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` are:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [29:8848]
:INPUT ACCEPT [29:8848]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6720:404317]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [96:8382]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o enp39s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [9418:3194873]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [17003:1327822]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

After a boot, `iptables --list -v` returns:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5587 packets, 1329K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wg0    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6845 packets, 956K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Note, in particular, that the FORWARD policy is DROP, not ACCEPT, and that WireGuard (`wg0`) rules are added.

Comment: Do you have rules that have "dynamic" interfaces in them, like rules based on a VPN interface that gets created?

Comment: I have a WireGuard interface `wg0` which is created on login (via `systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0.service`) The PostUp command for this interface is: `iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp39s0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp39s0 -j MASQUERADE`. The iptables rules that have been saved and that should be loaded by `netfilter-persistent` don't reference WireGuard, however.

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and adding your iptables rules?  My theory is that there is a rule in there that depends on an interface that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I've edited the post—thanks for helping, by the way.

Comment: Can you remove any/all Docker rules from your `rules.v4`? Docker should auto-create those rules when it starts.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and, following that, various other things around it. You were right to focus on Docker: it overwrites the FORWARD policy to DROP. See https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#docker-on-a-router. I still need to tinker, but I think the hardest part of the problem (to me) has been cracked. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: DOCKER chain should not be touched, but DOCKER-USER is the place to add rules